# Identity Login Logout Page Cs html file does not visible

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

**Please give me Any solution**

[image]

**When run the Project frontend will visible**

[image]

**But i cannot Found Cs html file**

[image]

THIS IS HAPPEN WHEN I ADDED THE CSHTML FILE

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create `.cshtml` as `view`? It should be only `Login.cshtml` because the `.cs` is for `Controllers` see the folder below

Comment: yes i trying to create .cshtml as View

Comment: when i run the project the login page will be visible

Comment: see i edit the question

Comment: What's the problem tho? It's already visible

Comment: Or can you spare some codes to share?

Comment: i want to edit login logout page but where i can edit there is no cshtml file.it is only C# code not cs or html code

Comment: Check on your `_ViewStart.cshtml`

Comment: Have you tried to create a new Solution Explorer,right click your solution and Select New Solution Explorer View

Comment: no not in  `_ViewStart.cshtml` file

Comment: i have mac there are not any option for new solution

Comment: see in project  Account folder

Comment: It usually doesn't visible by design. You can [check our offical document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). But you can get the `cshtml` file from our offical github repository.

Comment: when i added that file all text hide i add in question

Comment: i  re create identity so many but nothing will happn

Comment: Identity is managed by the `DLL` you cannot modify that but you can override or can extend the functionality. Could you please let us know what you exactly wanted to implement.

Comment: done i picked the file from github that file working

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed that you use cshtml as a file name, so

Just delete RegisterConfirmation.cshtml.cs and add it again as RegisterConfirmation.cshtml

Comment: nothing will  happen

Comment: i only want cs html code of login logout page