# How to Edit Image in Existing Member

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I Use bootstrap cards and i want picture can also edit on existing user or i Edit picture of any member

**This is my Controller**

This is my edit Functionality where i can edit My Member so i want i update all existing user picture

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var member = await _context.Member.FindAsync(id);
            if (member == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(member);
        }

        // POST: HomePage/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("MemberId,Name,Gender,DOB,MaritalStatus,Address,PhoneNo,Skills,Hobbies,JobTitle,Technology")] Member member)
        {
            if (id != member.MemberId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(member);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!MemberExists(member.MemberId))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(member);
        }
```

**This is a View of my project this is same as create class**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">MemberImage</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div id="chooseFile">
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

when i edit the one existing member
[image]

2.i add image
[image]

and save it will save the img but now they cannot save image

***Exception Occurs when i open edit***
[image]

***Edit Page Code**

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">MemberPicture</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <img src="~/ImageName/Cover/@Model.Member.ImageName"
                     class="rounded-square"
                     height="50" width="75"
                     style="border:1px"
                     asp-append-version="true" accept="image/*" />
                <span><a href="@Model.Member.ImageName">@Model.Member.ImageName</a></span>
                <div id="chooseFile">
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***View Model***

```
using System;
using TeamManagement.Models;

namespace TeamManagement.ViewModel
{
    public class MemberViewModel
    {
        public Member Member { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? Photo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your view? And what problem you are currently having with? Please narrate your problem description as well so that it can be resolve easily.

Comment: i only want When i Re-edit the member image will save on existing member

Comment: see i edit the question

Comment: It's Not clear how you are submitting a edit model from your edit view page.  Only can see the image upload input box

Comment: I just only want to know how to save it with edit functionallity

Comment: No worries I will try to explain as easy as possible, currently I am at gym will answer tomorrow.

Comment: i want to know that how update particular row field in table based on some condition

Comment: okok no problem

Comment: okok which workout are you done today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is my edit Functionality where I can edit My Member so I want I update all existing user picture?

If you look into the Member List, it usually contains rows of users along with `Id`. So we have to find the particular  `Id` and then need to retrieve the value of that `Id` finally we will update the existing value with the new value. As seen on the screenshot below

[image]

**Algorithm**

1. From The Member List Click On Particular Member Id
2. Find The Member Information By that Id
3. Load The Edit Page With That Id Same As Create Member Page
4. After Required Change Submit the Edit Page Which Containing the Member Model Data With A ID
5. Save the Image Into Folder First Same As Create
6. Search The Member Object By Id
7. Set New Value Into The Member Object You Have Found In Step 6
8. Save The Context And Redirect To Member List

**Controller Action For Loading Edit Page**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditMember(int memberId)
    {
        var memeber = await _context.Members.FindAsync(memberId); // Getting member by Id from database
        return View(new MemberViewModel() { Member = memeber });
       
    }
```

**View Model**

```
public class MemberViewModel
    {
        public Member Member { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? Photo { get; set; }
    }
```

**View Edit**

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.MemberViewModel
<div>
    <form asp-action="EditMember" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div><input type="hidden" asp-for="Member.MemberId" />
        <div>
            <h4><strong>Member Details</strong> </h4>

            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">

                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="Member.Name"></label></th>
                    <td> <input asp-for="Member.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter member name" /><span asp-validation-for="Member.Name"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="Member.Gender"></label></th>
               
                    <td>
                        <select asp-for="Member.Gender" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Member.Gender"></span>
                
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="Member.DOB"></label></th>
                    <td> <input asp-for="Member.DOB" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter animal category" /><span asp-validation-for="Member.DOB"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="Photo"></label></th>
                 
                    <td>
                        <img src="~/ImageName/Cover/@Model.Member.ImageName"
                             class="rounded-square"
                             height="50" width="75"
                             style="border:1px"
                             asp-append-version="true" accept="image/*" />
                        <span><a href="@Model.Member.ImageName">@Model.Member.ImageName</a></span>
                        <div id="chooseFile"><input type="file" name="photo"  accept="image/*" /></div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:107px">Update</button></th>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.ActionLink("Back To List", "MemberList", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })</th>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Here make sure your `src="~/ImageName/Cover/@Model.Member.ImageName"` is correct as per your picture location. Otherwise picture will not be displayed

**Controller When Submit Edit**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditMember(MemberViewModel model, IFormFile photo)
    {
        if (photo == null || photo.Length == 0)
        {
            return Content("File not selected");
        }
        //Save The Picture In folder
        var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "ImageName/Cover", photo.FileName);
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }

        //Bind Picture info to model
        model.Member.ImageName = photo.FileName;

        //Finding the member by its Id which we would update
        var objMember = _context.Members.Where(mId => mId.MemberId == model.Member.MemberId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (objMember != null)
        {
            //Update the existing member with new value
            objMember!.Name = model.Member.Name;
            objMember!.Gender = model.Member.Gender;
            objMember!.DOB = model.Member.DOB;
            objMember!.ImageName = model.Member.ImageName;
            objMember!.ImageLocation = path;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("MemberList");


    }
```

Here we will update the `_context.SaveChangesAsync()` instead of adding new data. This is the key point for edit. Update the information which we have got by `ID`

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Did you able to run my code? As said before, first run it then start your modification. I have commented each step clearly what the code is for. In addition, add your current `edit page load code` so that it can be understood clearly, screenshot in this case is not enouygh.

Comment: You are getting the because either your `model` has no image or you haven't set image for that `ID` try to make `public IFormFile? Photo { get; set; }` as nullable by putting `IFormFile?` or share your full `edit page code HTML` along with the `ViewModel`

Comment: `@model TeamManagement.ViewModel.MemberViewModel ` This is not correct Either share your full code or Post new question with your current code. Because its not clear what you are doing. The solution I have provided is very clear.

Comment: `ViewModel` should be like I have given the example. Your `View` is not getting the proper reference while loading, update your code the way I gave you the example.

Comment: Are you still struggling with the error?

Comment: which class or controller,view,Viewmodel Should i send

Comment: i have macbook is it working on macbook?

Comment: Nope it will not

Comment: ok .............

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72443430/18812706 this question issue